# I can't install winusb on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: apt, dependencies, windows-10, woeusb, winusb

So, I have been trying to install Windows 10 for quite a while now, and it is super frustrating. I can't just use ANY ISO burner, No, I have to use the 2 worst ones. woeusb and winusb. woeusb wont let me use my SD card because of a stupid number at the end of the device name (/dev/mmcblk0), and I can't even *install* winusb. When I attempt to install it, I get an error that says

```
dpkg: error processing package winusb (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

There are some dependencies that are uninstallable:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of winusb:
 winusb depends on libwxbase2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1); however:
  Package libwxbase2.8-0 is not installed.
 winusb depends on libwxgtk2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1); however:
  Package libwxgtk2.8-0 is not installed.
 winusb depends on gksu; however:
  Package gksu is not installed.
```

Some people told me to try sudo apt-get -f install, but when I try that, this is what I get:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  winusb
```

Somebody please help me. Is there a way for me to install winusb, or are there any alternative ways to get Windows 10?

Comment: Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/526485/338177).

Comment: You're wasting your time anyway. Currently MKUSB is the only tool able to burn the new Windows ISOs ib a way that will boot in BIOS and UEFI mode (you want the latter for any computer made in this decade)

Comment: @GabrielGarcia my computer actually used BIOS, not UEFI. It is old, but has a 64 bit processor

Comment: And I know for sure that windows works on it because I had it before I uninstalled it

Comment: Try according to [this link 'do it yourself'](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy) or try [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). See also [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive)

Comment: @sudodus Thanks, I will try that

Comment: Hey @SakerAlabas, did you find a solution? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: @PedroBatista Nope, the only solution I found is to just use a windows machine to create installation media, and I was eventually able to get my hands on a windows machine, so I was able to install windows

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below commands:

```
sudo apt update 
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/pool/main/w/woeusb/woeusb_3.3.0-1~webupd8~bionic0_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i woeusb_3.3.0-1~webupd8~bionic0_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -f
sudo dpkg -i woeusb_3.3.0-1~webupd8~bionic0_amd64.deb
```

launch it by searching the woeusb in applications.

[image]

Comment: thanks for trying to help, but as I said woeusb doesn't work.

Comment: I just did it with adding iso file, select file system to NTFS and chose the booting device (USB Drive) and clicked on install but it took almost 3 hours for completion.

Comment: the problem is that the device name of the SD card that I want to install to (the only big enough storage device I have) is called /dev/mmcblk0, and since there is a number at the end, woeusb doesn't accept it as a full device

Comment: check[named this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934608/cannot-burn-win10-on-usb-with-woeusb-winusb)

Comment: I tried all the solutions in that post, they don't work

Comment: It works for me.